# Tagger 404 Page

Tags: devdemon-tagger

We've used Tagger on a website and it works just fine, but the client would like a 404 error to display if someone manually typed in

Example:
http://www.example.com/projects/tags/education/

manually changed to 
http://www.example.com/products/tags/not-a-tag

results in a blank page vs. a 404.

```
{exp:tagger:entries_quick tag="{segment_3}"}
          <h1>Press Room: <span style="text-transform: capitalize;">{segment_3}</span></h1>
          {/exp:tagger:entries_quick}
          {exp:tagger:entries_quick tag="{segment_3}"}
          {exp:channel:entries channel="press_post" limit="5" dynamic="yes" entry_id="{tagger:entry_ids}" paginate="bottom"}
                    <div class="blogpost">
                        <div class="fourty">
                        {press_images limit="1"}
                            <img src="{image:url:small}" alt="" class="siteimage" />
                          {/press_images}
                        </div><!--fourty-->
                        <div class="sixty">
                            <h2>{title}</h2>
                            <p class="tags">

                {entry_date format="%M %j, %Y"} | Tags: 
          {exp:tagger:tags entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}
          <a href="{site_url}index.php/press-room/tags/{tagger:tag_name}/" class="taglink">{tagger:tag_name}</a>
          {/exp:tagger:tags}
```

I tried the below, but it doesn't forward off.
{exp:channel:entries channel="press_post" limit="5" dynamic="yes" entry_id="{tagger:entry_ids}" paginate="bottom"}
              {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}

Live Site: http://goo.gl/Dlsj2G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand your code, but I couldn't find any reason to split `exp:tagger:entries_quick` into two parts or where you're closing the second one, but I gonna try to help you.

You code doesn't work because the `exp:channel:entries` will never run if there is no results on `exp:tagger:entries_quick`.

Inside `{exp:tagger:entries}`, you can set a conditional `{if tagger:no_entries}`:

```
{exp:tagger:entries tag="{segment_2}" custom_fields="press_images"}

    {if tagger:no_entries}
        {redirect=""}
    {/if}
    <h1>Press Room: <span style="text-transform: capitalize;">{segment_3}</span></h1>

    [...]

{/exp:tagger:entries}
```

You can get more info on [Tagger docs](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/entries-tagger/).